# Error mbstring en PhpMyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu

al acceder a phpmyadmin me sale el siguiente error:

> The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP
>   configuration.

Bien ante lo cual investigue he intentado diferentes soluciones como reinstalar PhpMyAdmin:

```
   apt-get update
    apt-get install --reinstall phpmyadmin
    ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf
    a2ensite phpmyadmin
    service apache2 restart
```

lo cual lo hace bien , pero el error antes mencionado persiste.

**Solución 2 sin efecto:**

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

ejecutando dicho comando me sale:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete php7.0-mbstring no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia
a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente

E: El paquete «php7.0-mbstring» no tiene un candidato para la instalación
```

**Nota.-** uso Ubuntu 18.02

Gracias de antemano ..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dejare esta respuesta si alguien le sirve como referencia:
Primero desinstale PhpMyadmin:

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

Segundo desintalar PHP :

```
sudo apt-get purge 'php*'
```

Tercero reinstalar PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

con todo esto solucioné el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Hola comunidad yo tuve ese problema y mi versión de ubuntu es 18.04, y logre solucionarlo de la siguiente forma espero les sea útil.
inicialmente este problema es un conflicto con php 7.0 y es muy comun lo primero es parar el apache e instalar el php 7.1.

```
`$ service apache2 stop
 $ sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-common`
```

Luego instalaremos unos adicionales necesarios para laravel y composer.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl php7.1-xml php7.1-zip php7.1-gd php7.1-mysql php7.1-mbstring
```

una vez hecho esto verificamos la nueva versión de php.

```
$ php -v
```

van a ver algo similar a esto:

> PHP 7.2.4–1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 31 2019 11:06:48) ( NTS )

ya en este punto lo que hacemos es remover el PHP 7.0 que genera este conflicto o error

```
$ sudo apt-get purge php7.0 php7.0-common
```

ya purgado reinicias el servidor.

```
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

Por ultimo hacemos correr nuevamente el apache.

```
$ sudo a2enmod php7.2
$ service apache2 restart
```

Y así solucionas este problema ahora debes estar corriendo con php 7.2.